# Text difference from Firefox to Chrome

Tags: html, css

```
       <div id="slide1">            
       <span id="tf1">BUILDING YOUR HOME <br>TO BE COMFY AND WARM</span>
       </div> 

#tf1 {
opacity: 0.9;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
display: block;
color: /*#505050*/ #505050; 
text-shadow: /*#a8a8a8*/#9f9f9f -2px 1px 1px; 
font-size: 41px; 
font-family: Globerb;
}
#tf1::first-line {
color: /*#323232*/ #323232; 
text-shadow: /*#969696*/#8c8c8c -2px 1px 1px; 
font-size: 60px; 
font-family: Globerb;
display: block;
}
#slide1 {
/*transform: skew(0deg, 5deg);*/
opacity: 0;
position: absolute; 
padding-top: 40px; 
margin-left: 19.7916%;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

The problem is that in firefox, the text looks good 2 lines and thats all, but in chrome it goes into three lines. I have no idea why this is, but I guess that there is a some sort of fix via css?

Comment: You have to try [**CSS RESET**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)!

Comment: u can try this <p id="tf1">BUILDING YOUR HOME <br>TO BE COMFY AND WARM</p>,its working fine in Chrome and firefox and IE  without any CSS added

Comment: None worked :/ ajajajja

Comment: The only fix I found, which I don't seem to want to fix is to assign slide1 a fixed width. - so the problem is that chrome is wrapping my text in some manner.

Comment: i will attach the screen shorts in an answer u can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #tf1 {
opacity: 0.9;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
display: block;
color: /*#505050*/ #505050; 
text-shadow: /*#a8a8a8*/#9f9f9f -2px 1px 1px; 
font-size: 41px; 
font-family: Globerb;
}
#tf1::first-line {
color: /*#323232*/ #323232; 
text-shadow: /*#969696*/#8c8c8c -2px 1px 1px; 
font-size: 60px; 
font-family: Globerb;
display: block;
}
#slide1 {
/*transform: skew(0deg, 5deg);*/
opacity: 0;
position: absolute; 
padding-top: 40px; 
margin-left: 19.7916%;
margin-top: 0px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="tf1">BUILDING YOUR HOME <br>TO BE COMFY AND WARM</p>
</body>
</html>
```

chrome
[image]
firefox

[image]

ie[image]